# GCC / clang default error flag

Tags: compilation, gcc, clang

I am usually coding on OSX and compile all my program with : `-Wall -Wextra -Werror`

I download on another laptop `nixos` and when i want to compile the same project, i have `-Wunused-result` error.

I can disable it with : `-Wno-unused-result` but why this flag error appear on this os ?

I found nowhere a default flag configuration file or environment variable.

For curious the program i'm trying to compile is : [libft](http://github.com/ale-batt/libft).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're compiling on OSX and haven't *installed* **`gcc`**, Apple has provided **`clang`** pretending to be **`gcc`**.  The pretense isn't very good, since there are a lot of differences in warnings (and exit-codes).  You can see what you are running using

```
gcc --version
```

and (for instance ‐ I have installed gcc using MacPorts under `/opt`):

```
$ path -lL gcc
-rwxr-xr-x  3 root  admin  1131416 Jun 10  2016 /opt/local/bin/gcc
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  18176 Jul  8 22:52 /usr/bin/gcc

$ /opt/local/bin/gcc --version
gcc (MacPorts gcc5 5.4.0_0) 5.4.0
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ /usr/bin/gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

As you can see, **`/usr/bin/gcc`** is really **`clang`**, and (barring Apple improving things further), will produce similar messages.

Comment: This is why i wrote gcc / clang, i have the same error with both.